# Need to hover over menu before the element to be clicked on is available?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Need to hover over menu before the element to be clicked on is available!

`Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)` error on Selenium

I've tried this:

```
action.moveToElement(WebElement1);
action.moveToElement(WebElement2);      
action.click();
action.perform();
```

Comment: Please provide the html or the URL.

Comment: Selenium 2.32 standalone jar, FF 22 and site is peopleanswers.com the top navigation bar to the right .. say I want to click on ContactUs>Careers

Comment: Try chaining your commands into one line, with the `Actions()` class it really helps. `action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("id1")).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("id2")).click().build().perform();`

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation, using a combination of DriverBackedSelenium-click and JSExecutor worked for me. Refer to these links on how to use the same.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.jsp#how-to-migrate-to-selenium-webdriver

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me :

```
  private Actions builder; 
  builder = new Actions(driver);        
  builder.moveToElement(Elel).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

```
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        Action action1 = actions.moveToElement(webElement1).build();
        action1.perform();
        Action action2 = actions.moveToElement(webElement2).click().build();
        action2.perform();
```

Comment: This clicks on just one element , but I want to hovwe over one and click on another later

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue as provided via your comment, clicking upon the "Careers" link located within the "About Us" menu try the following:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("nav5")).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Careers")).click().build().perform();
```

Obviously, if you're wanting to click on other links that appear following a mouse-over action you'd just need to change the relevant `element` locators.